# It is not extracting the first element of array "integers" but extracts all other elements. Why?? Also how can i improve this code?

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0; i<11; i++){
    var slice;
    var secSlice;
    var digit = integers[i];
    document.write("digit:" + digit);
    var extract = digit.slice(1,2);
    extract == "-"? slice = digit.slice(2,digit.indexOf(",")) : slice = digit.slice(1,digit.indexOf(","));
    document.write(i +" :" + "("+ slice + ")");
}
```

It is not extracting the first element of array "integers" but extracts all other elements. Why?

Comment: can you post your code in jsfiddle and send url of fiddle here?

Comment: @LazarNikolic https://jsfiddle.net/8gr3tz5a/1/#&togetherjs=7wlQmju1Un

Comment: I was looking at your code and there are couple of things you should think about. First, do you need to store numbers inside array of arrays as strings? Wouldn't it be much simpler to save them as integers and then you would not have need to use as many slices as you did. Second, during the writing of your program, it is often of great help to use console.log to see what is going on with your data at particular moment of program's execution. Try to use this two advices and I believe that your code will function.